# Why i can't see new branch in tortoiseHG?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I create a new branch and commit it. But my team can't see this branch in their tortoise, why? 
[image]

Comment: Did they connect to your repository? Have you pushed to their repository? (I think this might not a good fit for Stackoverflow. [ask])

Comment: Yes, they connect to my repository!

Comment: How are they "connecting" to your repository? Please explain the steps you took to get the changesets from your repository over to the rest of your team. Did you push the changesets somewhere central, they pulled, but still can't see it? Or did they clone or pull directly from your repository? Or did they access a web server that you started on top of your repository? Please elaborate so that we may have more information needed to help you.

Comment: I clone repository, then i did changes in project, then i make commit to new named branch, then my teamate clone same repository to, and now he sees only default brunch, how he can find my new branch (user_to_b24) and switch it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only committed to your local clone of the repository.  You have to `hg push` the commit to the remote repository you originally cloned, if that is the repository the teammate is cloning.